# Troubleshot a connection refused from a fluentd td-agent process

Tags: ssh, fluentd

Using fluentd on my server I want to send data (stored in multiple .txt files) to another host host1

Here is the configuration file /etc/td-agent/conf.d/dump.conf

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /data/dump/**/*.txt
  pos_file /data/dump/spool/dump.log
  tag data.dump
  format none
</source>

<server>
  name host1
  host 10.yyy.xx.186
  port 24224
  weight 60
</server>
```

After restarting the td-agent deamon everything is ok, but not data are sent and I get a "Connection refused" error in the log

tail -n 1000 fluentd.log

```
2021-03-10 11:11:58 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of /data/dump/dump.agent.dump.logs.apache.error.log/2020/12/08/dump/logs/apache/error.log/202012080101_0.txt
2021-03-10 11:11:58 +0100 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2021-03-10 11:11:59 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-10 11:12:00 +0100 chunk="5bd28222fe5d47044eab3615df091bd6" error_class=Errno::ECONNREFUSED error="Connection refused - connect(2) for \"10.yyy.xx.186\" port 24224"
```

Which is suprising to me because I can ping host1 from my server without issue

```
ping 10.yyy.xx.186
PING 10.yyy.xx.186 (10.yyy.xx.186) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.yyy.xx.186: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms
64 bytes from 10.yyy.xx.186: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.179 ms
64 bytes from 10.yyy.xx.186: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.153 ms
^C
--- 10.yyy.xx.186 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2015ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.153/0.161/0.179/0.019 ms
```

My question is how do I reproduce the connection refused which appear in td-agent log files ?

**EDIT**

Following message from @Azeem, I added a log_level to `debug` in the fluentd conf file

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /data/dump/**/*.txt
  pos_file /data/dump/spool/dump.log
  tag data.dump
  format none
  @log_level debug
</source>

<server>
  name host1
  host 10.yyy.xx.186
  port 24224
  weight 60
</server>
```

And here are the log from the initialize part to the time errors occur.

```
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/socket.rb:59:in `initialize'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/socket.rb:59:in `new'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/socket.rb:59:in `socket_create_tcp'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:366:in `create_transfer_socket'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:678:in `send_data'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:295:in `block in write'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:330:in `block in select_a_healthy_node'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:324:in `times'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:324:in `select_a_healthy_node'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forward.rb:295:in `write'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1125:in `try_flush'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:1425:in `flush_thread_run'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin/output.rb:454:in `block (2 levels) in start'
  2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [warn]: #0 /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.4.2/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/thread.rb:78:in `block in thread_create'
2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of /data/dump/webmin/miniserv.error
2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of /data/dump/apache/error.log
2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of /data/dump/apache/error.2021-03-11.log
2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of /data/dump/apache/access.log
2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [info]: #0 following tail of /data/dump/apache/access.2021-03-11.log
2021-03-11 09:34:49 +0100 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
2021-03-11 09:34:50 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=1 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-11 09:34:51 +0100 chunk="5bd28222fe5d47044eab3615df091bd6" error_class=Errno::ECONNREFUSED error="Connection refused - connect(2) for \"10.yyy.xx.186\" port 24224"
  2021-03-11 09:34:50 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-03-11 09:34:51 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=2 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-11 09:34:53 +0100 chunk="5bd28222fe5d47044eab3615df091bd6" error_class=Errno::ECONNREFUSED error="Connection refused - connect(2) for \"10.yyy.xx.186\" port 24224"
  2021-03-11 09:34:51 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-03-11 09:34:53 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=3 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-11 09:34:56 +0100 chunk="5bd28222fe5d47044eab3615df091bd6" error_class=Errno::ECONNREFUSED error="Connection refused - connect(2) for \"10.yyy.xx.186\" port 24224"
  2021-03-11 09:34:53 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2021-03-11 09:34:56 +0100 [warn]: #0 failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=4 next_retry_seconds=2021-03-11 09:35:04 +0100 chunk="5bd28222fe5d47044eab3615df091bd6" error_class=Errno::ECONNREFUSED error="Connection refused - connect(2) for \"10.yyy.xx.186\" port 24224"
  2021-03-11 09:34:56 +0100 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
```

Comment: Please add your startup logs as well. Also, set the [`log_level`](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/logging#by-config-file) to `debug`.

Comment: Hi @Azeem I added the detail You requested, thank You for Your time !

Comment: Sure. Actually, you need to add all the startup logs, not just the errors. Also, did you test the output logs with `stdout`?

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/forward#example-configuration. You need a match section with `data.dump` tag to route logs and then under the `match` section you can configure your output targets.